# Python multiple variable assignment confusion

Tags: python

My first day in Python and get confused with a very short example. Hope anyone can provide some explanation about why there is some difference between these several versions. Please!

## V1: the output is 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8

```
a, b = 0, 1
while b < 10:
    print(b)
    a, b = b, a+b
```

## V2: the output is 1, 2, 4, 8

```
a, b = 0, 1
while b < 10:
    print(b)
    a = b
    b = a+b
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first version, the right hand is evaluated first, so `b` hasn't been incremented when you add it.

To step through the first version for a couple iterations:

1.

```
a = 0
b = 1
a, b = 1, 1  # b is 1, and a is 0
```

2.

```
a = 1
b = 1
a, b = 1, 2  # b is 1 and a is 1
```

3.

```
a = 1
b = 2
a, b = 2, 3  # b is 2 and a is 1
```

In the second version, `b` is assigned before you add it, so here's how the second version goes:

1.

```
a = 0
b = 1
a = b  # a is now 1.
b = a + b  # b is now 2, because both a and b are 1.
```

2.

```
a = 1
b = 2
a = b  # a is now 2.
b = a + b  # b is now 4, because both a and b are 2.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Morgan. So the priority of the right expression goes firstly, right?

Comment: @KelvinYe Exactly.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.